# Not getting "Scalar" dashboard in Tensorboard although code implemented

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm not getting a "Scalar" heading in the Tensorboard dashboard as I've seen in walkthrough videos, although I've implemented to required code as far as I can tell.

The relevant code I'm using is:

```
# cost and accuracy
with tf.name_scope("xent"):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=fc3l[0], labels=y)
    tf.scalar_summary('cross_entropy', cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(probs, 1), tf.argmax(y, 0))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', accuracy)

# init
sess = tf.Session()
merged_summary = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/tfvgg/1", sess.graph)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
```

I'm using Tensorflow version 0.11.0, and the headings that I am getting in Tensorboard are: "Events", "Images", "Audio", "Graphs", "Distributions", "Histograms", but not "Scalars".

The version of TF I'm using does not support implementations like `tf.summary.merge_all()` and `tf.summary.scalar()` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Are you _running_ `merged_summary` as well (i.e. `sess.run(merged_summary)` somewhere in your code? Summaries too are part of the Tensorflow computation graph and will not be calculated/refreshed if they are not _run_ periodically.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, after updating Tensorflow to version 1.0 I used the updated calls (`tf.summary.merge_all()`, `tf.summary.scalar()`) instead which have allowed for the Scalar heading in Tensorboard